# Matlab reloading file automatically

Tags: matlab

Is there any easy way to set a Matlab callback to execute a function whenever a specific file is modified? (I have a C++ program logging data and I want to run a Matlab script over that data everytime I execute the C++ program).

All I saw is that with `FileInfo = dir('data.txt')` I can get the date and create a script which is testing all the time if the last modification time has changed, but I do not like that solution.

Comment: There is no other way. Timer and periodic check of the file modification time. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/292357 + http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99277-how-do-i-programmatically-detect-a-change-in-a-directory . except .. `Starting with R2009a, MATLAB supports .NET objects such as the FileSystemWatcher, which can be used to work around this issue`

Comment: I haven't seen that one, bad news then :(. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Look at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9957-using-net-filesystemwatcher-to-listen-for-new-files

Comment: That last one is too much for what I need but thank you! Although I cannot make it work since it returns an error.

Comment: You do not need everything from there. Just a listener and function that runs on selected event.